# print_r($_POST) doesn't print anything

Tags: php

why I can't print the contests of `$_POST` in this code? I've tried using `print_r($_POST), echo $_POST, var_dump($_POST)` but no content is displayed on the screen.

Here is the full page:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("../controller/loginFuncs.php");
\asc\checkLogin();

require_once '../controller/database/MySQL_DataMapper.php';

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

try {
    $mapper = \asc\MySQL_DataMapper::getInstance();
    $result = $mapper->fetchAllOMs();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    var_dump($_SESSION);
//    $militar = new \asc\Militar($_POST['cpf'], $_POST['fname'], $_POST['lname'], $_POST['organizacao_militar'], $_POST['posto']);
//    $mapper->cadastrarMilitar($militar);
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>ASC | Principal</title>

    <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="../images/favicon_package_v0.16/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="../images/favicon_package_v0.16/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="../images/favicon_package_v0.16/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="../images/favicon_package_v0.16/site.webmanifest">
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="../images/favicon_package_v0.16/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">

</head>

<body class="top-navigation">

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="page-wrapper" class="gray-bg">
        <?php include "menu.php";?>
        <div class="row wrapper border-bottom white-bg page-heading">
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <h2>Cadastro Militar</h2>
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item">
                        <a href="../index.php">Principal</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item">
                        <a>Cadastro</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item active">
                        <strong>Militar</strong>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="ibox ">
                        <div class="ibox-title">
                            <h5>Entre com as informações do militar</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ibox-content">
                            <form method="post">
                                <div class="form-group  row"><label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">CPF</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10"><input name="cpf" type="text" class="shouldValidate cpf form-control" required></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
                                <div class="form-group  row"><label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Nome</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10"><input name="fname" type="text" class="shouldValidate fname nome form-control" required></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
                                <div class="form-group  row"><label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Sobrenome</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10"><input name="lname" type="text" class="shouldValidate lname nome form-control" required></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
                                <div class="form-group  row"><label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Telefone</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10"><input name="telefone" type="tel" class="phone_with_ddd form-control"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
                                <div class="form-group  row"><label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10"><input name="email" type="email" class="email form-control"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
                                <div class="form-group row"><label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Organização Militar</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <select id="om-dropdown" class="shouldValidate form-control m-b" name="organizacao_militar" required>
                                            <option></option>
                                            <?php
                                                $last_FA = null;
                                                foreach ($result as $OM){
                                                    if ($OM->getForcaArmada() != $last_FA) {
                                                        $last_FA = $OM->getForcaArmada();
                                                        echo '<option disabled></option>';
                                                        echo '<option disabled>────────────────────  '.$last_FA.'  ────────────────────</option>';
                                                    }
                                                    echo '<option'.' value="'.$OM->getIdEncrypted().'"'.'>'.$OM->getNome().' ('.$OM->getSigla().')'.'</option>';
                                                }
                                            ?>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
                                <div class="form-group row"><label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Posto</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <select id="ajaxop" class="shouldValidate form-control m-b" name="posto" required>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2">
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit">Cadastrar</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php include "footer.php";?>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Mainly scripts -->
<script src="../js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.mask.js"></script>
<script src="../js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#om-dropdown').change(function () {
            var id = $(this).val();
            $("#ajaxop").html("<option>Carregando ...</option>");
            $.post("../controller/loadPostos.php", {OM: id}, function (data, status) {
                $("#ajaxop").html(data);
            });
        });
        $('.cpf').mask('000.000.000-00', {placeholder: "___.___.___-__", reverse: true});
        $('.phone_with_ddd').mask('(00) 00000-0000', {placeholder: "(__) _____-____"});
        $('.fname').keyup(function (e) {
            var regex = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
            var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
            if(code == 32) {
                alert('Digite apenas o primeiro nome neste campo.')
            }
            this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]+/, '');
        });
        $('.lname').keyup(function () {
            var regex = /^[a-zA-Z\ ]+$/;
            this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z\ ]+/, '');
        }).focusout(function () {
            $(this).val($.trim($(this).val()));
        });
        $('.email').focusout(function () {
           if ($(this).val() && !validateEmail($(this).val())) {
               alert('Email inválido!');
           }
           $(this).val($.trim($(this).val()));
        });

        $('.shouldValidate').on('change invalid', function() {
            var textfield = $(this).get(0);

            textfield.setCustomValidity('');

            if (!textfield.validity.valid) {
                textfield.setCustomValidity('Por favor, preencha este campo.');
            }
        });

        function validateEmail(email) {
            var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
            return re.test(email);
        }
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Everything else works fine so far, now I'm trying to get the contents of the form with the method post, and print them out before trying to save it to the database. But nothing is shown to me.

Comment: Where in your code is the `print_r($_POST)`?

Comment: are you accessing the page from a POST request? If you're doing it through chrome, you're doing a GET. Try using something like Postman. Alternatively, you can use $_REQUEST, although it's typically frowned upon

Comment: You should move the error reporting stuff above the include/require. If there are errors in the included files it could be killing your script before you turn error reporting on.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte It is right at the beginning, but in the code I posted `var_dump($_POST)` was used, nevertheless `print_r($_POST)` was also used, and did not produce any results either.

Comment: @ChadK Not quite sure what are you asking, I'm trying to get data from a form using the method post, like it is usually done. If you scroll down the code, there will be a form with a `method="post"`, and then in the php part of it, I try to capture the contents of the $_POST array by doing: `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` this has always worked for me, but there is something wrong now.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Thank you for the tip, will do so.

Comment: @AlexandreKrabbe I was just making sure you're accessing the page via a POST request. How are you creating the post and viewing the results? Using the Chrome inspect/network? If you view it from Postman or Chrome's inspect/network tab, you can see what type of response you get. If it's a 500, there's something wrong with the server and code. If it's a 200, it's completing the request normally

Comment: I see a few things, You don't have a submit button, you just have a submit type. Not sure how browsers handle those. Also, in your form you don't have an 'action'. When you omit the action (<form action="postpage.php">), the browser will automatically submit the data to /action_page.php

Comment: @ChadK Not sure what Chrome inspect/network or Postman are, maybe I should take a look at it. I'm trying to view the results with a `var_dump($_POST)`. The php code that checks if it is a post request is indeed in the same page. Felippe posted and answer saying the I should name the button, maybe that is it. Will check that as soon as I get to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a name=submit to your button

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" name="submit">
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that out in a couple hours as soon as I get to work and then let you know what happened, hope it solves the problem.